# When you use DRF(Server API) + React(public Web Client), how do you implement for OAuth2 social login?

Tags: django, reactjs, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am developing Django(Server) with React(Web Client).

And I want to use facebook social login.
I knew that client is public client, server is confidential. So I want to use authentication code grant way for authenticating user.
So I find out the way but there is no way to implement that. All the python oauth2 library limplements is just for django server side rendering.(Django Server + Web client).

So I confused about I am wrong or just the others just did not make the grant way.

When you use DRF(Server API) + React(public Web Client),
how do you implement for OAuth2 social login?

I wonder that. please give me some advise to me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from basics, people usually split frontend and backend to improve the production speed as frontend and backend can be developed by two separate teams. But in order for the frontend and backend to work together, there needs to be a connection interface, an API.
React is a frontend that runs in the browser, so in order to talk to the server, it uses a REST protocol. 
As the backend in this scenario is Django we use DRF as React uses REST API. DRF provides easy flexible pre-built packages to carry out this communication job between server and client.
 
Now the authenticator for web login you choose to be Facebook hence you will get the identity token from facebook, which will correspond to the rows in the Django User table which will give you access to the user's data in Django.

You don't need to do everything at once, you need to first implement the Facebook social auth and after test(test using postman app) only think about connecting React

A good place to start is this DRF documentation, look into Social OAuth2 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-oauth-toolkit

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I wonder if there is not a proper way to implement *authentication code* way.

Comment: you can see https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/72   https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Comment: I want code for library which writes about /oauth2/callback/?code=AUTH_CODE

Comment: When I used social login, I used this app, but I didn't use DRF but the workflow should be same. You don't need to any other library. Like I said, First implement login using the template, once you have finished that, connect DRF, in theory you dont even need DRF to get authentication. The user cookie being transfered holds Django User table details. Try this First, https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html